# Working with Conditional Formatting and Multiple Rules

Tags: excel

I have two columns. 1st column is an expected completion date (ECD). 2nd column is a actual completion date (ACD), which starts out blank. I want the ECD to turn red if its date is in the past...easy. I want the ECD to turn back to white if there is an ACD filled in.

To me the formula would be: =AND(A3:A5 < TODAY(), B3:B5 IS NOT BLANK) But that formula is not allowed.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you setup conditional formatting you have to be very careful about how you specify things. When setting up your formulas you only reference the 1st row of your AppliesTo range, excel will adjust the references as it moves down the range. Of course this will be different if you are referencing cells that are not in your first row. If referencing constants remember to use the $ for the rows/columns that don't change.

In this specific case the formula you want is: =AND(A3<(TODAY()),B3=0,A3<>0)

[image]

Comment: Works great! Thank you.